# What are the official FrameworkNames?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

.NET 4 has a new [FrameworkName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.frameworkname.aspx) class. An example of this being used is NuPack and its package directory [naming convention](http://nupack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Package).

What are the FrameworkNames for Microsoft's .NET Frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see for yourself when you change the MSBuild output to Diagnostic.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  The string you'd pass to the FrameworkName constructor appears as the `TargetFrameworkMoniker` build property.

The ones I can easily see myself are the regular desktop version:

> .NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client

And the Silverlight version:

> Silverlight,Version=v4.0

Contributed by the OP, the Windows Phone 7 version:

> Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone

I can't get any Micro Framework projects built, instant crash to the desktop.  Compact Framework support was removed from VS2010. That's about it for versions that I know of.

Comment: I do have Windows Phone 7 installed which is the one I was interested in. It is: "Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the target framework for any project with the following command:

```
$p = Get-Project "MyProjectName"
$p.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value
```

You can execute it also from Visual Studio -> Package Manager Console.

[Good explanation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html)